# Access - Do not select a text box by default on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I have an access program with a splash screen at the start. 
On the splash screen, two text boxes are shown: "Component" and "Version", which are linked to a table with those values in. My problem is this:
Even though the text box properties are set to Tab Stop = No and Back Style = Transparent, the first text box still selects itself and the text is selected and does not look good.
The actual form's "Allow additions, edits, etc" are all set to No and Data Entry is off. Here is what happens when the form is opened:
[Highlighted Text Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QETfc.png)

I have tried to stop it by turning tab stop = no and turning off all the options that allow data to be entered or edited. I want it to not be highlighted. How can I achieve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Design view, set both text boxes to

```
Enabled = No
Locked = Yes
```

This way they can't get the focus.